# Tracing an error message when starting Tmux or Vim

Tags: vim, git, zsh, tmux

Recently when I start Tmux on my Mac (with Powerline) in iTerm, I get an error `git: Permission denied`. I also get the error over and over again as I type in Vim (also using Powerline). As you can tell, the theme seems to be Powerline in all this. I've uninstalled and reinstalled Powerline and still get the error.

Before I say "screw it, I'm done using Powerline," I was wondering if there's a way that I can trace the error to find out exactly what is calling Git on a directory/file where it's not allowed?

PS I have also run through Repairing the Permissions on my system with the Disk Utility.

**Edit:** I've completely uninstalled Powerline and still am seeing the same issue. When I start Tmux (or open a new pane in Tmux) or save a file in Vim, I get the error from above.

**Edit2:** This is what I see when I open Terminal and run `dmesg`

```
git: Permission denied
git: Permission denied
~/Projects › sudo dmesg | tail -n 20
Password:
smb1_smb_negotiate: Support for the server XRX9C934E142236 has been deprecated (PreXP), disconnecting
smb1_smb_negotiate: Support for the server XRX9C934E142236 has been deprecated (PreXP), disconnecting
smb1_smb_negotiate: Support for the server XRX9C934E142236 has been deprecated (PreXP), disconnecting
fsevents: watcher dbfseventsd (pid: 10879) - Using /dev/fsevents directly is unsupported.  Migrate to FSEventsFramework
smb1_smb_negotiate: Support for the server XRX9C934E142236 has been deprecated (PreXP), disconnecting
smb1_smb_negotiate: Support for the server XRX9C934E142236 has been deprecated (PreXP), disconnecting
smb1_smb_negotiate: Support for the server XRX9C934E142236 has been deprecated (PreXP), disconnecting
smb1_smb_negotiate: Support for the server XRX9C934E142236 has been deprecated (PreXP), disconnecting
smb1_smb_negotiate: Support for the server XRX9C934E142236 has been deprecated (PreXP), disconnecting
SerialATAPI device reconfiguration did not complete successfully.  (failedCommandInfo = 0x1)
smb1_smb_negotiate: Support for the server XRX9C934E142236 has been deprecated (PreXP), disconnecting
smb1_smb_negotiate: Support for the server XRX9C934E142236 has been deprecated (PreXP), disconnecting
smb1_smb_negotiate: Support for the server XRX9C934E142236 has been deprecated (PreXP), disconnecting
smb1_smb_negotiate: Support for the server XRX9C934E142236 has been deprecated (PreXP), disconnecting
smb1_smb_negotiate: Support for the server XRX9C934E142236 has been deprecated (PreXP), disconnecting
smb1_smb_negotiate: Support for the server XRX9C934E142236 has been deprecated (PreXP), disconnecting
         0 [Level 5] [Facility messagetracer] [com.apple.message.domain com.apple.kernel.cs.mismatch] [com.apple.message.signature 1000] [com.apple.message.signature2 53a18aae61685cc356b171ce37cc504048ed45a1] [com.apple.message.signature3 b928c695e1e1a867d5fc392eb8f09e460f3139af] [com.apple.message.summarize YES]
         0 [Level 5] [Facility messagetracer] [com.apple.message.domain com.apple.kernel.cs.invalidate] [com.apple.message.signature invalidate] [com.apple.message.signature4 27386] [com.apple.message.signature3 GoogleSoftwareUp] [com.apple.message.summarize YES]
CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x1000): p=27386[GoogleSoftwareUp] final status 0x0, allow (remove VALID)ing page
smb1_smb_negotiate: Support for the server XRX9C934E142236 has been deprecated (PreXP), disconnecting
```

Comment: Have you tried dmesg | grep some_keyword?

Comment: What would I put in place of "some_keyword"?

Comment: Try git, given that the error you receive concerns it.

Comment: It gives me nothing. I do have to run dmesg with elevated permissions though (`sudo dmesg | grep git`)

Comment: Then try, immediately afer receiving the error message, dmesg | tail -n 20

Comment: @MariusMatutiae see the update on my question.

Comment: Here you have a Samba problem.

Comment: I'm not connecting to any Samba shares though.

Comment: I did look and the Samba error seems to be that there's some system on our network running Pre-XP. Shouldn't effect Git though.

Comment: Do you get the permission denied error every time a new prompt is drawn? What happens if you start without config, i.e. issue `zsh -f`, and save a file in `vim`?

Comment: Does it happen when working in a local git repo or anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ultimately found the problem to be with the system installed Git. When I installed Git with Homebrew and overrode the system Git with the Homebrew Git I stopped getting errors.